# Can't change text of control

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a simple winforms application which does some task every 30 seconds (using a timer). There is a function which is called each time its "time event" is raised.

In this function I am also trying to change some text that appears in some label. I try to do it by calling `BeginInvoke` - but this does not change the text.

Then I also try to call it by simple `.Text = "some Text"` - but this also did not work.

How can I change the control's properties?

Comment: please post some code so we can see how you are attempting the change.

Comment: Could you post some code? BeginInvoke is only necessary when using threads.

Comment: Are you sure your timer tick event is actually firing?  Please post the timer setup and starting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need BeginInvoke only if you are working with threads. Otherwise following should work:

```
label.Text = "some Text";
Update();
```

Comment: If the code is single-threaded and timer-launched method is long, than update is necessary. Otherwise window will remain unrefreshed until something will forces it to repaint (mouse-over, minimize & restore,...).

Comment: for some reason its did not work for me. i change the update place in the code and somehow its started to work and solve the problem for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `BeginInvoke` in this case. Form-based timers do not call from a separate thread. Simply replace your invoke code in the timer's tick event handler with a straightforward update of the label's text property. Like: `myLabel.Text = "Timer event fired";`

Comment: I try to simple call the text property in the way you describe - and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need only use the `Timer` control. And write your code in the `Timer_tick` event handler.